# Jellybean Offline Recognition in Python

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Can JellyBean's offline speech recognition be used in Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you can someshow get an API of google speech recognition, which I think is present on the web somewhere. Then using it in python won't be a problem you could use SL4A for programming in python and make an .apk by compiling your app with python interpreter.